# Open cover of $\mathbb Q$ which is pairwise disjoint

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, intuition

Using the fact that the Lebesgue measure is countably additive, it is trivial to prove that $\mathbb Q$ has measure zero. However, in order to gain an intuition for this fact, I thought it would be instructive to consider the following equivalent definition of *null set*:

> A set $E\subset \mathbb R$ is a *null set* if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a countable collection $A$ of open intervals such that $E\subset\bigcup A$, and the sum of the lengths of those intervals is less than or equal to $\varepsilon$.

If we enumerate $\mathbb Q$ in some manner, then we can let
$$
A=\left\{\left(q_0-\frac{\varepsilon}{4},q_0+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\right),\left(q_1-\frac{\varepsilon}{8},q_1+\frac{\varepsilon}{8}\right),\left(q_2-\frac{\varepsilon}{16},q_2+\frac{\varepsilon}{16}\right),\dots\right\} \, ,
$$
where $q_i$ denotes the $i$-th rational. Then, we clearly have $E\subset\bigcup A$, and the the sum of the lengths of the intervals is $\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/4+\varepsilon/8+\dots=\varepsilon$. While this does make things more intuitive for me, I don't find this explanation totally satisfying because of the "overlap" between the intervals in $A$.

**Question:** Fix an $\varepsilon>0$. Is there an explicit example of set $A$ with the following properties:

- A is a countable collection of open intervals that covers $\mathbb Q$,
- The sum of the lengths of the intervals in $A$ is less than or equal to $\varepsilon$,
- $A$ is pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Well, there's a question of what you would consider "explicit".  For instance, you could just take the intervals that are the connected components of the union of the intervals in your example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can every open set of $\mathbb{R}$ be written as countable union of disjoint open bounded intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905871/can-every-open-set-of-mathbbr-be-written-as-countable-union-of-disjoint-ope)

Comment: I'm curious regarding why the explanation is not "totally satisfying". Given a cover with overlaps, removing the overlaps while retaining it as a cover is only going to shrink the sum of lengths.

Comment: @AnneBauval No, because that question does not ask for any controls on the measure of that collection of intervals.

Comment: @AnneBauval:  Indeed the proposed duplicate involves an entirely different setting ($\mathbb R$ rather than $\mathbb Q$) and concerns writing an open set as a countable union of open intervals.

Comment: @hardmath The setting is the same ($\mathbb R$ in both cases). The union of the (overlapping) open intervals above (covering $\mathbb Q$) is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, to which the proposed duplicate applies, thus answering the present question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson the sum of the measures of the new intervals (given by the duplicate) is less than or equal to that of your collection, since the new intervals are pairwise disjoint and have the same union as yours.

Answer (score 2):

This is really the same argument, just with a little care to make sure that the sets are disjoint. In particular, if the cover is of the form $U_{j}=(a_j,b_j),$ we need to have $a_j,b_j$ irrational, because no open set can contain $a_j$ or $b_j$ and be disjoint from $U_j.$

Enumerate the rationals $(r_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}.$

We will construct an increasing sequence $(i_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of positive integers and a sequence of positive irrational numbers $(\delta_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ so that the intervals $U_j=(r_{i_j}-\delta_j,r_{i_j}+\delta_j)$ are disjoint and cover the rationals and $\sum 2\delta_j<\epsilon.$

Let $\alpha<\epsilon/2$ be an irrational number.

Define $i_1=1, \delta_1=\alpha/2.$ Let $U_1=(r_1-\delta_1,r_1+\delta_1).$

Given values for $j=1,\dots,n-1,$ find the smallest $i_{n}$ such that $r_{i_n}\notin \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} U_j.$

Define $$\delta_{n}=\min\left(\alpha/2^{n},\left|r_{i_{n}}-r_{i_j}\pm \delta_j\right|\mid j=1,\dots,n-1\right).$$

$\delta_n$ is irrational (and hence non-zero) and non-negative because it is the minimum of a finite set of non-negative values, all irrational.

$\delta_n$ is chosen to be no bigger than $\alpha/2^n,$ but also so that $U_{n}=(r_{i_n}-\delta_n,r_{i_n}+\delta_n)$ is disjoint from the previous $U_j.$

Then we get that the $U_j$ cover all rationals (why?) and are disjoint, and $\sum\mu(U_j)\leq \sum 2\delta_j<\epsilon.$

---

This works for rationals because we can pick $\delta_i$ irrational to make sure that no rational is on a boundary of one of the $U_j.$ It will be slightly harder in the general countable case. But not much harder.

Show the lemma:

> If $X$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb R,$ $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $\delta>0$ there exists a $0<\delta'\leq \delta$ such that $x_0-\delta',x_0+\delta'\not\in X.$

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. A rough sketch: start with a set $A = \{A_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of intervals which have irrational endpoints, cover $\mathbb{Q}$, and have total length $< \epsilon$.

Enumerate the rationals with $q : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. For each $n$, pick an interval $I_n$ with irrational endpoints as follows: Pick the least $j < n$ such that $q_n \in I_j$ and let $I_n = I_j$, if such a $j$ exists; otherwise, let $j$ be the least $j$ such that $q_n \in A_j$, and let $I_n$ be the connected component of the interior of $A_j \setminus \bigcup\limits_{j < n} I_j$ which contains $q_n$.

Then we see that $\{I_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable set of pairwise disjoint intervals whose union is $\mathbb{Q}$ and whose total length does not exceed that of $A$, which is $< \epsilon$.